# Cast an NSDictionary value while applying an NSPredicate?

Tags: cocoa, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I have an Array of NSDictionary objects. 
These Dictionaries are parsed from a JSON file.
All value objects in the NSDictionary are of type NSString, one key is called "distanceInMeters".

I had planned on filtering these arrays using an NSPredicate, so I started out like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(distanceInMeters <= %f)", newValue];
NSArray *newArray = [oldArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

I believe this would have worked if the value for the "distanceInMeters" key was an NSNumber, but because I have it from a JSON file everything is NSStrings.
The above gives this error:****** -[NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3936f00***

Which makes sense as I had just tried to treat an NSString as an NSNumber.

Is there a way to cast the values from the dictionary while they are being filtered, or maybe a completely different way of getting around this?

Hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(distanceInMeters.floatValue <= %f)", newValue];
```

Comment: Hi Homer
Thanks that did the trick:) I did not know that you could type cast like that, NSPredicates on anything else that NSManagedObjects is new to me:)

Thanks again

Comment: FYI, it's not type-casting; it's just calling the "floatValue" method on NSString.

Comment: Ahh Thanks I get it, it is of course accessing the property directly instead of the accessor [NSString floatValue]:)

Comment: No, it's calling the accessor. NSString doesn't have a "floatValue" property to access directly. And in general, NSPredicates access things using the valueForKey: method for each dot-separated component. valueForKey: uses an accessor if available, or direct access to the ivar of not. Just because the predicate syntax uses a dot doesn't mean that it's using properties. And even if it were, if NSString had a "floatValue" property, accessing it would be IDENTICAL to calling [thatString floatValue].

Comment: This isn't working for ints ?? Trying to do predicate on nsstring property but comparing as an int.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't the predicate; your problem is that you're dealing with `NSString` objects instead of dealing with `NSNumber` objects.  I would focus my time on changing them to `NSNumbers` first, and then verify that it's not working.

FYI, the [JSON Framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework) does automatic parsing of numbers into `NSNumbers`...

Comment: Hi Dave, thank you, yes I would also prefer to deal with the correct types:)
I looked at the JSON library I am using, it does scan for numbers. Then I tried this:
 BOOL theBool = [[dict objectForKey:@"distanceInMeters"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]];
 NSLog(@"The value of the bool is %@\n", (theBool ? @"YES" : @"NO"));

It comes back YES, so no doubt. I am using SBJSON could it be that it is simply no working?